# Maven EJB Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

Which is the best way to create a Maven Project in Eclipse to support an EJB Session Bean development?

Note: I'd like to use the last version (`7`) of Java EE API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use Adam Biens [javaee7-essentials-archetype](https://github.com/AdamBien/javaee7-essentials-archetype)

mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=com.airhacks:javaee7-essentials-archetype

it creates a new project constisting of a minimal pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: yep sure, it can easily be changed in the properties section of the pom.xml